# How move object between scenes

Tags: workflow, objects, scene

I have two scenes in a blend file. How do I move a object from one scene to the other? Not between blend files, but within one blend file but two scenes.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> to copy and paste objects from one scene to the next. They will be placed into the new scene at there original global coordinates. If you want the objects modified in one scene to update in the other,<kbd>Spacebar</kbd>>*Link Objects to Scene*(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> - *Thanks gandalf3*).

Comment: Small note, *link objects to scene* is also accessible with `Ctrl L`

Answer (score 8):

*I'm not allowed to comment on the accepted answer (insufficient rep) so I was forced to duplicate it in order to add my two cents.*

---

1. Select one or more objects in your donor scene. [How?](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Selecting)
2. While holding <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> press <kbd>C</kbd> to copy these objects to a buffer.
3. Switch to recipient scene. [How?](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Interface/Scenes)
4. While holding <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> press <kbd>V</kbd> to paste items from the buffer.
5. Delete the original objects or donor scene as desired.

Notes:

1: From what I can tell —regardless of settings— the objects will be placed into the new scene using their previous global coordinates.

2: Upon completing step 4, if all your scenes get duplicated, it is because one or more of your objects has an active scene actuator in the "set scene" mode. Disabling the actuator before doing step 2 is sufficient to prevent this issue.

3: For step 2, pressing <kbd>L</kbd> instead of <kbd>C</kbd> allows object linking.

4: This answer should be valid for almost all versions of Blender. I've only tested on Blender 2.74 however.