# How to import an object across scenes (sort-of)

Tags: objects, scene

I have already made the Cyodrake's Gaze for my animation, but I really don't want to have to do it all over again for scenes 6, 7, 31... and so forth.

Is there any way to copy/paste an object into scenes?

Thanks, Nefer007

Comment: Possibly related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14455/how-move-object-between-scenes?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do that you just link the object to the new scene, and then make it a single user object.

1. Select object in Scene 1
2. In the Object menu, choose Make Links <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> > Objects to Scene > Scene 2 (or whatever scene you want to link it to.
3. At this point the object is not a separate copy from the Scene 1 object. To make it separate, with the object selected, open the Object Menu, choose Make Single User >  Object (or one of the other options if appropriate)