# Knowing the angle of the camera

Tags: camera

This is a newbie question, but I want to do several scenes with the camera placed at a specific angle to the object (assuming the object is placed on the grid). I can't find any settings for the current angle of the camera. I need to know what position it is in for the next blender file I create.

So how can I position the camera at exact location for different blender projects / files?

Thanks!

Comment: You can copy camera from one scene to another, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14455/how-move-object-between-scenes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your camera selected open the properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>) and take a look at the top part, the *Transform* section.
[image: Transform section of the properties panel]

Here you can see, and change, the exact location and rotation of your camera. (Or any [active object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21050/2217), not just the camera.)

You can get to the same information my going to the *Object* tab of the properties window, I just prefer to stay in the 3D view.

So for your two scenes, you can simply pick a location and orientation that you like, then copy the transformational values to your other camera.

Comment: Cool, just what I was looking for, thanks alot! :)