# Groups from scene to scene

Tags: scene

How to send group of objects from scene 1 to scene 2 ?

I have group in scene 1 which I would like to use in scene 2.

Comment: select all group objects, then make link to the scene 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a group instance in another scene just do so from the Add menu with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Group Instance* > *Group name*.
If you want to move objects themselves between scenes use [method of copying and pasting or linking](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14455/how-move-object-between-scenes).